# python numpy memory leak inside loop

Tags: python, numpy, for-loop, memory-leaks

Memory leak issue in array1:

```
for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(dataset_path):
    for mfile in files:
        [...]
        for x in list:
            array1 = calculate_big_array()
        del array1
```

I tried:

- del array1
- gc.collect()
- UPDATE: gc.set_debug(gc.DEBUG_LEAK) :Prints no uncollected items

and also tried to define array1 outside loop so that I make sure that it keeps the same id and not create others but the problem remains.
It seems that in every loop a different array1 is added in memory and leads to memory leak.
Any ideas?

Comment: `del array1` is just decreasing the reference count for array1, I think you should take a look at how python gc works. So, the arrays will be erased from memory when python consider, so don't worry too much about that unless there is any specific reason for it.

Comment: @Netwave thanks but how can I properly release memory in my case?

Comment: `del array1` and then call to the gc, its the only thing you can handle. But this will probably slow your code down.

Comment: you may want to read this post about this: http://numpy-discussion.10968.n7.nabble.com/Numpy-s-policy-for-releasing-memory-td1533.html

Comment: I cannot understand where I keep the reference  and it is not completed deleted.

Comment: how do you know the 'big arrays' are accumulating?  If that's all you are doing you don't need del or gc.

Comment: @hpaulj I checked with a memory profiler that the memory increases in each loop after the calculation of the big arrays

Comment: Why do you even assign the returned array to a variable if you don't do anything with it?  I suspect there  is something important that you aren't showing us.

Comment: @hpaulj indeed it was caused by the framework used to calculate the big array but it seemed that it was the array's fault based on the memory profiler stats